# rails 4.2.0, sass-rails 5.0.1, and bootstrap-sass 3.3.3 Undefined variable: "$state‐danger‐text"

Tags: bootstrap-sass, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I'm trying to follow Michael Hartl's [Ruby on Rails Tutorial 3rd Edition](https://www.railstutorial.org/) with a slightly modified Gemfile and Sassy CSS files. When I try to use bootstrap-sass variables and mixins to display bootstrap powered validation errors in my custom.css.scss I get "Undefined" error.

I've confirmed that the variable exists in my {"bundle show bootstrap-sass" path}/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss It seems like it doesn't lookup that file before throwing the error.

Please let me know how to fix this issue. Thanks a lot!

Here is my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.0'
# Use pg as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg', '0.18.1'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.23.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.3.3'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '5.0.1'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '2.7.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.1.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.0.3'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '2.5.3'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '2.2.6'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '0.4.1', group: :doc

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', '3.5.1'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring', '1.2.0'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.3'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

Here is my application.css.scss

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 */

 @import "bootstrap-sprockets";
 @import "bootstrap";

 @import "custom.css.scss"
```

And Here is my custom.css.scss

```
#error_explanation {
  color: red;
  ul {
    color: red;
    margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  }
}
.field_with_errors {
  @extend .has‐error;
  .form‐control {
    color: $state‐danger‐text;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After 20 hours, I finally found out that I get the error only when I copy the codes from the tutorial to sublime text 2. I wrote every related line myself and it is now working as it should, no errors. May be some weird character is sneaking in when I copy. Quite strange!